# Java JPA Load balancing read queries to Read MySql DB slave

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I noticed that my Play Framework application is not sending the read queries to the read-only MySql slave.

I am using

1. `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver`.
2. `jdbc:mysql:replication://write-db-url,read-db-url/db_name` as `javax.persistence.jdbc.url`
3. The db's are `AWS aurora` `MySQL-compatible` with `multi-az` replica.
4. I am using `hibernate` as ORM.
5. I am using `play framework`.

Am I missing any configuration/code?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example: what you do and what errors/unexpected result do you get?

Comment: There is no error as such, but select queries are not being sent to the read replica.

Comment: Surely JPA has some configuration??

Answer (score 0):

Everything else looks good as stated in question, like `jdbc` `driver` and `url`.

Because in your question very less information is provided related to ORM or JPA and connection codes that you are using.

I'm here by providing a simple main program that you could use debug your issue. Once that is done, focus on your app to see, are you missing same thing.

Here is how `JDBC` driver determines, whether to connect `master` or `read replica`.

1. If connection mode is `read+write`, which is `default`, then it goes to `master`.
2. If connection mode is `read`, then it goes to one of `read-replica`.

Here officially [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html).

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ReplicationDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Properties props = new Properties();

// We want this for failover on the slaves
props.put("autoReconnect", "true");

// We want to load balance between the slaves
props.put("roundRobinLoadBalance", "true");

props.put("user", "foo");
props.put("password", "password");

//
// Looks like a normal MySQL JDBC url, with a
// comma-separated list of hosts, the first
// being the 'master', the rest being any number
// of slaves that the driver will load balance against
//

Connection conn =
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/test",
        props);

//
// Perform read/write work on the master
// by setting the read-only flag to "false"
//

conn.setReadOnly(false);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE some_table ....");
conn.commit();

//
// Now, do a query from a slave, the driver automatically picks one
// from the list
//

conn.setReadOnly(true);

ResultSet rs =
  conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT a,b FROM alt_table");

 .......
}
}
```

Hope it helps.